# Layout error with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having difficulty getting the page to display correctly after the user logs in to  my system. Most of the code I've written is taken from a tutorial and adapted to suit my needs which is why I've run into problems! I'd like to run the `dishes_management()` method inside the `index()`. However If I do this the style of the page is completely distorted.

If I just load the `index()` as normal and then click on one of the links in my `example.php` view it will open and display perfectly! Why is this?

```
class Examples extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');   
}

function _example_output($output = null)
{
    $this->load->view('example.php',$output);

}

function index()
{
    $this->_example_output((object)array('output' => '' , 'js_files' => array() , 'css_files' => array()));
}   

function dishes_management()
{
    try{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('dishes');
        $crud->set_subject('Dish');
        $crud->required_fields('dish_name');
        $crud->columns('dish_name','dish_desc','dish_price', 'dish_cat');

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
```

example.php

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url('examples/dishes_management')?>'>Dishes</a> |
    <a href='<?php echo site_url('examples/orders_management')?>'>Orders</a> |
```

Comment: How do you mean the style is distorted? Are the Style sheets being loaded? Do you get an error?

Comment: I don't get any errors, the style sheets seem to be loaded but not correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write comment on the original question so I will leave it as an answer for now. If this violates any of Stack Overflow policy, please go ahead and delete it.

If the style of a page gets destroyed, it's most likely that the path of css link tags are relative path, instead of absolute path generated by `site_url(<some_path>)`. Check if this is the case.